# How can I simplify this javascript excerpt. In particular how do I set named object properties from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I would like to simplify this code fragment but can't get the syntax right to deconstruct an array into an object.

```
let result = this.getSomething(x, y, z);
return { a: result[0], b: result[1] };
```

Comment: This is fine. There is no destructuring syntax to extract from array *and* create an object at the same time. Closest is an IIFE: `return (([a, b]) => ({a, b}))(result);`  but not very readable. Your code is fine.

Comment: Who cares about readable I want it as fancy as possible :)

Comment: Added a jsfiddle to illustrate how this works (as took me a while to understand the answer).
https://jsfiddle.net/03gautow/